# React Redux functional component updating state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My data looks like this:

```
{

  '004': [
      {
          year_week: '2020-W1',
          actual_bank_amount: '6500000',
          ext_in_rental_income: '',
          ext_in_tax_refund: '',
          ext_in_dividends_income: ''
      },
      {
          year_week: '2020-W2',
          actual_bank_amount: '6500000',
          ext_in_rental_income: '',
          ext_in_tax_refund: '',
          ext_in_dividends_income: ''
      }

  ],
  '007': [
      {
          year_week: '2020-W22',
          actual_bank_amount: '65050000',
          ext_in_rental_income: '30000',
          ext_in_tax_refund: '',
          ext_in_dividends_income: ''
      }

  ]
},
```

I am trying to update say date for year_week '2020-W1' in '004'.

No problem with action and reducer but data is not updated in the list.

Below is my reducer:

```
case 'UPDATE':
  state.planningData[action.payload.currentSite].map((item, index) => {
    if (item.year_week === action.payload.data.year_week) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, action.payload.data);
    }
    return item;
  });
  console.log(state)

  return {
    loading: true,
    planningData: state.planningData,
    error: ''
  }
```

What I am doing wrong please. Btw when I do console log or run redux extension  I see the updated state.

Below is my action creator:

```
export const update = (data) =>

    (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log("Update action called" + JSON.stringify(data))
        const currentSite = getState().sites.currentSite;
        dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE',
            payload: {
                data: data,
                currentSite: currentSite
            }

        });
    };
```

btw I am calling it from a editable cell component on "enter" and blur event below is my code

```
 const save = async e => {
        try {
            const values = await form.validateFields();

            toggleEdit();
            dispatch(update({ ...record, ...values }));
        } catch (errInfo) {
            console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you share your actionCreator and also snippet of where it is being called.

Comment: Updated my question above. If I am using a plain array instate of nested one in the list it just work fine. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `console.log(state)` in your reducer print what you're expecting? Also, should loading property be toggled to false if update was successful? And last suggestion, maybe try saving the map into another variable `let adjPlanningData` and then in the return statement have planningData point to the above variable.

Comment: console.log(state) doesnot print what I am expecting in this approach. but previously I followed another approach which was showing the console log correctly,but off course my source list in the UI was not updated

Comment: `state.planningData[action.payload.currentSite].map((item, index) => {
  if (item.year_week === action.payload.data[0].year_week) {return Object.assign({}, item, action.payload.data)} return item  }) console.log(state.planningData) //Shows as expected return { loading: true,  planningData: state.planningData,  }`

Comment: Above code shows state updated , I am stacked badly please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but it works. You had a bit of nested data in your state and it wasn't being updated properly.

```
    case "UPDATE":
      let updatedPlanningData = {};
      for (let prop in state.planningData) {
        if (prop === action.payload.currentSite) {
          updatedPlanningData[action.payload.currentSite] = state.planningData[
            action.payload.currentSite
          ].map((item, index) => {
            if (item["year_week"] === action.payload.data.year_week) {
              return Object.assign({}, item, action.payload.data);
            }
            return item;
          });
        } else {
          updatedPlanningData.prop = state.planningData[prop];
        }
      }
      return {
        loading: true,
        planningData: updatedPlanningData,
        error: ""
      };
```

Here is example code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-engelbart-yfxh6?file=/src/App.js)

Edit: more compact solution

```
let updatedPlanningData = {...state.planningData};

updatedPlanningData[action.payload.currentSite].map((item, index) => {
        if (item["year_week"] === action.payload.data.year_week) {
          return Object.assign(item, action.payload.data);
        }
        return item;
      });
```

Comment: @Nabajit Roy does this help ?

Comment: i agree. this is pretty messy not your code per say, but the way we are handling this logic inside of a reducer. I recommend OP look into using `immer` or handle some of the logic in the action it self. All the reducer should be doing is updating the state.

Comment: @BARNOWL Totally agree. Edited with neater solution.

Comment: @BARNOWL I will have a look and let you know. Anyways thank you very much for your time .